# Как правильно получить настоящую дату в LibGDX

Tags: java, дата, libgdx, calendar

Все доброго времени суток.
Вопрос довольно простой, но мне это никак не даёт покоя.
Я использовал такой код:

```
private String getDate() {
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        String s = day + ":" + month + ":" + year;
        return s;
    }
```

Собственно, на данный момент дата такая: 24.11.2020.
Этот метод возвращает 24.10.2020.
Почему он возвращает октябрь а не ноябрь ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так месяцы возвращаются с нуля , а не с единицы)
Ноябрь - 10, Декабрь - 11, Январь - 0

А для получения нужной вам даты можете вот так попробовать сделать:

```
private String getDate() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    return dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Блин, я даже не знал, большое спасибо за ответ)

Comment: добавил еще вариант решения вашей проблемки)